# How to update multiple docs in nested array of arrays? (MongoDB 3.6)

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update all `customerId` props in multiple deeply nested arrays:

```
// Collection before update
[{
  cycle: [
    [[{customerId: "1"}], [], [], [{customerId: "1"}], [], [], []],
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], []],
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], []],
    [[], [{customerId: "1"}], [], [], [], [], []],
  ]
}]

// Collection after update
[{
  cycle: [
    [[{customerId: "2"}], [], [], [{customerId: "2"}], [], [], []],
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], []],
    [[], [], [], [], [], [], []],
    [[], [{customerId: "2"}], [], [], [], [], []],
  ]
}]
```

I'm running MongoDB 3.6. I've tried various combinations of `$`, `$[]`, `$[<identifier>]` and `arrayFilters` :

```
db.arrayTest.update({},     
  { "$set": { "cycle.$[].$[day].customerId": "2"}},     
  { arrayFilters: [{"day.customerId": "1"}] }   )
// WriteResult({
//  "nMatched" : 0,
//  "nUpserted" : 0,
//  "nModified" : 0,
//  "writeError" : {
//    "code" : 28,
//    "errmsg" : "Cannot create field 'customerId' in element {0: [ { customerId: \"1\" } ]}"
//  }
// })

db.arrayTest.update(
  {"cycle.$[].$[].customerId": "1"},     
  { "$set": { "cycle.$[].$[].customerId": "2"}}
)
// WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

db.arrayTest.update(
  {"cycle.$.$.customerId": "1"},     
  { "$set": { "cycle.$.$.customerId": "2"}}
)
// WriteResult({
//  "nMatched" : 0,
//  "nUpserted" : 0,
//  "nModified" : 0,
//  "writeError" : {
//    "code" : 2,
//    "errmsg" : "Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'cycle.$.$.customerId'"
//  }
// })
```

I've also tried various queries without much success:

```
db.arrayTest.find({"cycle.$.$.customerId": "1"})
// ""

db.arrayTest.find({"cycle.$[].$[].customerId": "1"})
// ""

// The following works but requires using explicit array indices
db.arrayTest.find({"cycle.0.0.customerId": "1"})
// { "_id": ObjectId("5bdbeae940eedc517cafb84f"), "cycle": [
//     [
//       [{ "customerId": "1" }],
//       [],
//       [],
//       [{ "customerId": "1" }],
//       [],
//       [],
//       []
//     ],
//     [
//       [],
//       [],
//       [],
//       [],
//       [],
//       [],
//       []
//     ],
//     [
//       [],
//       [],
//       [],
//       [],
//       [],
//       [],
//       []
//     ],
//     [
//       [],
//       [{ "customerId": "1" }],
//       [],
//       [],
//       [],
//       [],
//       []
//     ]
//   ] }
```

The following query works:

```
db.arrayTest.find({"cycle": {$elemMatch: { $elemMatch: { $elemMatch: { "customerId": "1"}}}}})
```

Comment: Can you also include of what you have tried and what is exactly the error that you encountered?

Comment: @Andreas Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB 3.6+ [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) work well for this. The MongoDB 3.6 release also adds the `$[]` and `$[<identifier>]` [multi-element array update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#multi-element-array-updates). For example:

```
db.arrayTest.insertMany([{
  array: [
    [[{id: "1"}], [{id: "2"}], [], [{id: "1"}], []]
  ]
}])


db.arrayTest.update({},
    { $set: { "array.$[].$[].$[el].id": "updated" } },
    { arrayFilters: [{"el.id": "1"}], multi: true}    
)

db.arrayTest.find({})
// [{
//   array: [
//     [[{id: "updated"}], [{id: "2"], [], [{id: "updated"}], []]
//   ]
// }]
```